On Partial $u$-Substitution to Evaluate $\int \frac {14e^{3x}\mathrm dx}{(e^{3x})^2 + 1}$
In evaluation of the integral below, the author started with u-substitution:
$$\int \frac {14e^{3x}\mathrm dx}{(e^{3x})^2 + 1}$$
The author says $u=e^{3x}$ and that $\mathrm du=3e^{3x}\mathrm dx$. If the author substituted $u$ into the integral, they'd get:
$$\int \frac {14u\mathrm dx}{(u)^2 + 1}$$
This leaves no room for $\mathrm du$ to be substituted in because there are no $e^{3x}$s left and $\mathrm du=3e^{3x}\mathrm dx$. However, the author then goes on to write this:
$$\int \frac {14\mathrm du}{(u)^2 + 1}$$
I think they arrived at this integral by only substituting $u$ in the denominator instead of substituting $u$ in both the numerator and the denominator. This approach leaves an $e^{3x}$ in the numerator which the author could substitute $\mathrm du$ in for.
My question is whether or not this is fine. If you are doing $u$-substitution, don't you have to substitute $u$ into the whole integral and not just part?

The entire $e^{3x} \ dx$ part comes from the $du$ part: it's $\frac{1}{3} \ du$. You don't need extra terms from $u$ to get the $e^{3x}$ in the numerator.  Is that what you're asking?

Of course, the factor of $1/3$ has been omitted, to add to the confusion.

$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =14 \int \frac{e^{3 x}}{\left(e^{3 x}\right)^2+1} d x \\
& =\frac{14}{3} \int \frac{d\left(e^{3 x}\right)}{\left(e^{3 x}\right)^2+1} \\
& =\frac{14}{3} \tan ^{-1}\left(e^{3 x}\right)+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Your integral is $$\int\frac{14(e^{3x})}{(e^{3x})^{2}+1}dx$$
Now substitute $e^{3x}=u$. Which gives $3e^{3x}dx=du$
Therefore we can write the given integral as :
$$\frac{14}{3}\int\frac{3e^{3x}}{(e^{3x})^{2}+1}dx=\frac{14}{3}\int\frac{1}{u^{2}+1}du$$
Which implies that the result of the following integral is
$\frac{14}{3}\tan^{-1}(u)+C=\frac{14}{3}\tan^{-1}(e^{3x})+C$
